# For set theory and operations, how would A=B be true, given the options?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $C$ is a fixed non-empty set, which one of the following options imply $A=B$?

1) $A - C = B - C$

2) $A \cup C = B \cup C$

3) $A \cap C = B \cap C$

4) $A \Delta C = B \Delta C$

I'm not sure why all of them are not valid option.

The problem I'm having is with premise. If $A=B$ then it would imply that all of the options are true. Can you maybe expand that a bit more on how to reason the problem?

Comment: Have you tried doing this with some specific examples? Using only sets with a few elements you can come up with counterexamples for each of 1-3.

Comment: The problem I'm having is with premise. If $A=B$ then it would imply that all of the options are true. Can you maybe expand that a bit more on how to reason the problem? @T.Bongers

Comment: I think you have the implication backwards. The question is asking "does $A - C = B - C" imply that $A = B?" and so on. Not assuming that $A = B$.

Comment: @FrankPinto Include your comment in your post instead so people see you at least _thought_ about the problem, rather than giving people the impression you copy-pasted it here looking for someone to do your work.

Comment: HINT: take $A=\{1,2\}, C=\{1\}, B=\{2\}$. Then $A\cup C=B\cup C$, but $A\not=C$. Do you see what this has to do with part (2) of your question?

Comment: Hint A={1,2,3}, B={1,2} and c={1}. How can you show 3) does not imply A=B?

Comment: "The problem I'm having is with premise. If A=B then it would imply that all of the options are true. "  Yes, but the those options being true do not imply $A=B$.  implication is a One-way, not two way, street.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem I'm having is with premise. If $A=B$
>   then it would imply that all of the options are true. Can you maybe expand that a bit more on how to reason the problem?

You seem to have misunderstood what the problem is. Taking part (b) as an example, you are right that
$$A=B \quad\text{ implies }\quad A\cup C = B\cup C $$
but that's not what is being asked here. Instead you're asked to determine whether
$$ A\cup C = B\cup C \quad\text{ implies }\quad A=B $$

In this case the answer is that *it doesn't*, as shown by the counterexample
$$ A = \varnothing, \quad B=\{1\}, \quad C=\{1\} $$
where $A\cup C=B\cup C$ is indeed true but $A=B$ isn't.

Answer (score -1):

Your mistake is having the implication backwards.  You are correct that $A=B$ implies each of them, but that isn't what is being asked.  You are being asked which of them implies $A=B$.  For (2), for example, there could be an element that is in $A$ and $C$, so is in both unions, but is not in $B$.  That makes $A \neq B$ even though $A \cup C = B \cup C$

There are $2^3=8$ possibilities for an element to be in some combination of $A,B,C$.  Because of the symmetry of $A$ and $B$ you can ignore the ones where it is in $B$ and not $A$ because the result will be the same for one that is in $A$ but not $B$.  You can also ignore the ones where it is in both or neither of $A,B$.  Consider an element that is in $A$, not in $B$, and maybe in $C$, so there are only two real possibilities.  See if either of them work with your equalities.  If either one does, that equality does not imply $A=B$.

Answer (score -1):

> The problem I'm having is with premise. If A=B then it would imply that all of the options are true.

Which is the exact *reverse* of what is being asked.

The question isn't what can we conclude from $A=B$.  It is what can we use to conclude $A=B$.

If the question was "Which one of these imply Charlie is a mammal" and the first option was "Charlie breaths" then

Although "Charlie is a mammal" $\implies$ "Charlie breathes",

"Charlie breathes" $\not \implies$ "Charlie is a mammal".

So that is *not* an answer.

=====

1) A−C=B−C

The fails as $A$ may have different elements of $C$ than $B$ does.

2) A∪C=B∪C

Ditto.

3) A∩C=B∩C

This fails because $A$ may have different elements that are not is $C$ than $B$ does.

4) AΔC=BΔC

If believe $A \Delta C = (A\setminus C)\cup (C\setminus A)$.  Am I correct?

If so $A\Delta C$ are all the elements of $A$ that are not in $C$ and all the elements in $C$ that are not in $A$.  These are equal to all the elements of $A$ that are not in $B$ and all the elements in $C$ that are not in $B$.

So all the elements of $A$ that are not in $C$ are the same as the elements in $B$ that are not in $C$. And the elements in $C$ that are not in $A$ are the same of the elements of $C$ that are not in $B$.

That means the *rest* of the elements in $C$ that *aren't* in $A \Delta C$ are  elements in $A$.  And the elements in $C$ that aren't in $B \Delta C$ are elements in $B$.  And this are the same elements.

So the elements of $A$ that are not in $C$ are the same as the elements of $B$ that are not in $C$.  And the elements of $A$ that *are* in $C$ are the same as the elements of $B$ that are in $C$.

So $A$ and $B$ have the same elements.

This is the only one that applies.

Comment: The question:  "Can you maybe expand that a bit more on how to reason the problem?"  The question was not "Can you maybe expand that a bit more on how to reason the problem, and prove or disprove that $A=B$ in each and every of the four set relations"?  And the OP did *not* assume the *"opposite"* of what is being asked.  In fact, they assumed the ***converse*** of what is being asked.